# Change position of Toast in android api 30

Tags: android

I wanted to change the toast from the bottom of the screen to the top, but I found that
"Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts." - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Toast#setgravity

Is there still a way to change the position? Or is that not at all possible anymore?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible anymore.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve the same effect a different way?

Comment: Don't use a `Toast`. In your own activity, you can position things wherever you want.